# 3D alpha shape for finding the boundary of points cloud in python

Tags: python, points, convex-hull, divide-by-zero, concave-hull

I'm trying to find the surface of points cloud using the 3D alpha shape algorithm. When I calculate the circumradius, the determinant a is equal to zero, leading to the error 'divide by zero encountered in double_scalars'. What should i do with it? Thanks a lot! Here is the code:

```
def alpha_shape_3D(points, alpha):
    tetra = Delaunay(points)
    edge = []
    for i1, i2, i3, i4 in tetra.vertices:
        pa = points[i1]
        pb = points[i2]
        pc = points[i3]
        pd = points[i4]
        pa2 = np.dot(pa, pa)
        pb2 = np.dot(pb, pb)
        pc2 = np.dot(pc, pc)
        pd2 = np.dot(pd, pd)
        a = np.linalg.det(np.array([np.append(pa, 1), np.append(pb, 1), np.append(pc, 1), np.append(pd, 1)]))

        Dx = np.linalg.det(np.array([np.array([pa2, pa[1], pa[2], 1]),
                                     np.array([pb2, pb[1], pb[2], 1]),
                                     np.array([pc2, pc[1], pc[2], 1]),
                                     np.array([pd2, pd[1], pd[2], 1])]))

        Dy = - np.linalg.det(np.array([np.array([pa2, pa[0], pa[2], 1]),
                                       np.array([pb2, pb[0], pb[2], 1]),
                                       np.array([pc2, pc[0], pc[2], 1]),
                                       np.array([pd2, pd[0], pd[2], 1])]))

        Dz = np.linalg.det(np.array([np.array([pa2, pa[0], pa[1], 1]),
                                     np.array([pb2, pb[0], pb[1], 1]),
                                     np.array([pc2, pc[0], pc[1], 1]),
                                     np.array([pd2, pd[0], pd[1], 1])]))

        c = np.linalg.det(np.array([np.array([pa2, pa[0], pa[1], pa[2]]),
                                    np.array([pb2, pb[0], pb[1], pb[2]]),
                                    np.array([pc2, pc[0], pc[1], pc[2]]),
                                    np.array([pd2, pd[0], pd[1], pd[2]])]))
       
        r = math.sqrt(math.pow(Dx, 2) + math.pow(Dy, 2) + math.pow(Dz, 2) - 4 * a * c) / (2 * abs(a))  # error occurs here, since some value of a is zero.
        if r<alpha:
            edge.append([pa,pb,pc,pd])
    tetras = np.array(edge)
    # triangles
    TriComb = np.array([(0, 1, 2), (0, 1, 3), (0, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3)])
    Triangles = tetras[:,TriComb].reshape(-1,3)
    Triangles = np.sort(Triangles,axis=1)
    # Remove triangles that occurs twice, because they are within shapes
    TrianglesDict = defaultdict(int)
    for tri in Triangles:TrianglesDict[tuple(tri)] += 1
    Triangles=np.array([tri for tri in TrianglesDict if TrianglesDict[tri] ==1])
    #edges
    EdgeComb=np.array([(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2)])
    Edges=Triangles[:,EdgeComb].reshape(-1,2)
    Edges=np.sort(Edges,axis=1)
    Edges=np.unique(Edges,axis=0)

    Vertices = np.unique(Edges)
    return Vertices,Edges,Triangles
```

Answer (score 0):

Without your `points` data it's hard to say for sure, but it looks like your data is degenerate. For example, if all your points are on the same plane you can get this result.